# pandas - Creating a database of pro cod league and I am having trouble accessing certain things

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I am trying to sum up all the match wins for each team, there are 12 different teams and each row has "team" and "match win". I want to be able to sum up the match wins for each team but I am running into a ton of errors with the ways I have tried to do it. I tried to use iterrows and iteritems but it just creates a tuple with (0, rest of data). Any help would be extremely appreciated!

[image]

Here is my code and here is my results. The picture shows how my db is formatted,

```
for i in df.iteritems():
    #for k in team:
    print(i)
    #reak;
#tdf = df["match win"].iteritems()   
print(tdf)
```

Here is my output examples
('match id', 0       1
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
..
315    10
316    10
317    10
318    10
319    10
Name: match id, Length: 320, dtype: int64)
('game id', 0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
..
315    5
316    5
317    5
318    5
319    5
Name: game id, Length: 320, dtype: int64)
('match win', 0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      1
..
315    1
316    0
317    0
318    0
319    0
Name: match win, Length: 320, dtype: int64)
('mode', 0       hp
1       hp
2       hp
3       hp
4       hp
...
315    snd
316    snd
317    snd
318    snd
319    snd
Name: mode, Length: 320, dtype: object)
('final score', 0      194
1      194
2      194
3      194
4      250
...
315      6
316      2
317      2
318      2
319      2

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
df.groupby('team')['match win'].sum()
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept my answer by checking the tick besides my answer and also give it an upvote if it was helpful. Happy coding!